# SQL query. Get similar rows ordered by desc

Tags: sql

I have a simple table with two fields.

1) book_id - int

2) tag_id - int

One book can have multiple tags, such as

```
book_id:1 - tag_id: 2, 3, 5, 9
```

Here is the question: how can i get a similar books from specific book? Also, they should be ordered desc by something like "likeness" count.

Example: i wanna get all book_ids with similar tags from book_id = 1 ordered by similar tags count.

**Specific book**: book_id: 1 - tag_id: 2, 3, 5 , 9

**Result:**

```
book_id: 54 - tag_id: 2, 3, 5, 14

book_id: 104 - tag id: 2, 3, 10
```

Comment: I don't in any case answer questions with 'wanna' in them, but see [Why should I provide an MCRE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: (1) Tag with the database you are using.  (2) Define what YOU mean by "similar tags".

Comment: You've mentioned in a [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61908526/sql-query-get-similar-rows-ordered-by-desc#comment109500164_61909342) that you're using MySQL saying "Your request doesn't work for me (i've tried to transfer to Mysql')". Why have you not edited your Question to include this, when you've been asked to already?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can order the books by the number of tags they have in common with your given book:

```
select bt2.book_id, count(*) as tags_in_common
from book_tags bt join
     book_tags bt2
     on bt.tag_id = bt2.tag_id
where bt.book_id = ?
group by bt2.book_id
order by tags_in_common desc;
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's say your table and data look like this:

```
create table #books_tags(
    book_id int,
    tag_id int
)

insert into #books_tags values(1, 2), (1, 3), (1, 5), (1, 9)      -- book_id:1
insert into #books_tags values(54, 2), (54, 3), (54, 5), (54, 14) -- book_id:54
insert into #books_tags values(104, 2), (104, 3), (104, 10)       -- book_id:104
insert into #books_tags values(2, 3), (2, 5), (2, 11), (2, 14)    -- book_id:2
insert into #books_tags values(3, 3), (3, 9), (3, 10), (3, 11)    -- book_id:3
```

Then your query is this:

```
select a.book_id, 
       b.book_id similar_book_id, 
       count(*) matching_tags, 
       string_agg(a.tag_id, ',') tag_ids
from #books_tags a
left join #books_tags b on b.tag_id = a.tag_id and b.book_id <> a.book_id
group by a.book_id, b.book_id
order by matching_tags desc, a.book_id
```

(in SQL Server 2017 or later)

Comment: Your request doesn't work for me (i've tried to transfer to Mysql'). This works for me, but my table has about 1m records and this query take for about 8 sec (even with limit 10). How can optimise it? Should i add indexes for tag_id field? 
SELECT g1.book_id, count(*) as match_count from book_tags g1 join book_tags g2 on g2.tag_id = g1.tag_id and g2.book_id = 731 where g1.book_id != 731 group by g1.book_id order by match_count desc limit 10

Comment: You haven't mentioned that you work with MySQL.
You need to have an index on tag_id column.